# GeoTIFF appears only as a black solid image

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I need to open a GeoTIFF file (high resolution aerial image) but for some reason it appears only as a black solid image and nothing else. I've tried opening with QGIS and Windows photo viewer so far.  What can I do to solve this?

Comment: This could just be a statistics issue

Comment: Can you include a GDALinfo -stats listing in your question? I would suggest you avoid using non-spatial viewers like photo viewer or photoshop to open geolocated rasters... they tend to break the georeference.

Comment: Is it possible the reason to be rendering issue?